# Read specific chunk of bytes in flutter / dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to read just a chunk of bytes from a file in flutter not the whole data?
For example from byte 50 to 150

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

```
Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
File file = File('${directory.path}/myfile.txt');
RandomAccessFile raf= file.openSync(mode: FileMode.read);
raf.setPositionSync(50);
Uint8List data = raf.readSync(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```dart
final file = File(filePath);
final fileStream = file.openRead(50, 150);
final bytes = await fileStream.toList();
```